# Traefik: Aggregate multiple docker services into a single logical backend

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, minio

I'm running minio using its official [docker-compose file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/minio/minio/master/docs/orchestration/docker-compose/docker-compose.yaml) which creates 4 services (containers): minio1,minio2,minio3,minio4. Traefik treats them as 4 unique services, but in reality, they should be treated as a single backend, that is, I want Traefik to generate 1 frontend an 1 backend (with 4 servers) for minio.
I tried putting them into a single group(servicefabric.groupname) but to no avail.
I have the following labels set for each minio service:

```
  labels:
    - "traefik.servicefabric.groupname=minio"
    - "traefik.basic.frontend.rule=Host:foo.bar.com"
    - "traefik.weight=10"  # 10,20,30,40 incremented per service
    - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik"
    - "traefik.port=9000"
  container_name: minio*
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All minio services have to have the same frontend rule and the same backend name.

```
  labels:
  - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:minio.${DOMAIN}"
  - "traefik.backend=minio"
  - "traefik.port=9000"
```

Also I think you misunderstood the meaning of "backend". A backend is a server to which Traefik route traffic based on the frontend rules. Same as "upstream"/"location" in nginx.

---

Edit

As stated in the comment, this configuration creates multiple frontends all pointing to the same backend, although functional this looks ugly. A quick solution is to just have one service with ‘frontend’ but if that service goes down, the frontend will be gone too.

A better way to do this is to set it in the config file, traefik.toml:

```
[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
  backend = "minio"
    [frontends.frontend1.minio]
    rule = "Host: minio.${DOMAIN}”
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved exactly 50% of my question, which is quite a big step from the beginning!
Now I have 1 backend with 4 servers, but still 4 frontends pointing to the very same backend, which is still good, but pointless IMO.
How do I wrap up the all minio frontends into a single one?

I know what a frontend and backend is, but according to Traefik's terminology, a backend is made up of one or multiple servers and I had 4 backends with a single server. I wanted 1 backend with 4 servers --> 1 nginx upstream with 4 servers. same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I did what you recommended, but no change. I've tried every possible (according to my own limits) variations, but no luck. It feels like my [frontends] block is completely ignored in my traefik.toml file. I've set Traefik's logger to debug and dumped it to a file. This is what I get when I recreate my Traefik container: https://pastebin.com/ZhUKMSbx    
This is what I have in my minio's docker-compose file (labels):     - "traefik.backend=minio"
    - "traefik.port=9000"
    - "traefik.weight=10"
    - "traefik.enable=true"

Any idea, maybe?

Comment: @Riverman I personally never used the file config, but some said you have to put [file] in order for it to work.

Comment: Thanks Siyu, when I put a [file] in my config, the web GUI started to show interest in my custom-defined frontend rules so this is going to be the right approach. It's not perfect yet, needs some more tinkering, but I think I'm getting close to the final solution. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

@Riverman

I had the same issue as you and I solved it by playing around as it's not fully documented in Traefik documentation. What you need to do is specify the `traefik.backend` value for all the services to be the same name and set `traefik.frontend.backend` to that `traefik.backend` value. You can't use the service piece for this. Below is an example.

```
services:
  minio01:
    image: minio/minio
    hostname: minio01
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - minio01-data:/export
    networks:
      - minio
      - traefik
    command: server http://minio01/export http://minio02/export
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.docker.network=traefik'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:minio.local'
      - 'traefik.frontend.backend=minio'
      - 'traefik.port=9000'
      - 'traefik.protocol=http'
      - 'traefik.backend=minio'

  minio02:
    image: minio/minio
    hostname: minio02
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - minio02-data:/export
    networks:
      - minio
      - traefik
    command: server http://minio01/export http://minio02/export
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.docker.network=traefik'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:minio.local'
      - 'traefik.frontend.backend=minio'
      - 'traefik.port=9000'
      - 'traefik.protocol=http'
      - 'traefik.backend=minio'
```